# Inequality for the difference of square roots of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

For $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$, I would like to know if there is a universal constant such that either
$$
|\sqrt{a + b} - \sqrt{a}| \leq \frac{C |b|}{\sqrt{|a| + |b|}}.
$$
or 
$$
|\sqrt{a + b} + \sqrt{a}| \leq \frac{C |b|}{\sqrt{|a| + |b|}}.
$$
I have computed this sum on several examples and it seems to be true but I would like a formal proof.

Comment: which branch of the square root are you taking?

Comment: For concreteness, let's say the branch cut is along the negative real axis and we take the standard branch.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=-1-\epsilon\, i$, $b=2\,\epsilon\, i$. Then $\sqrt{a+b}\sim i$ and $\sqrt{a}\sim-i$ hence $|\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt{a}|\sim2$ as $\epsilon\to0$, while the right hand side is smaller than $2\,C\,\epsilon$.

For the inequality to hold you will have to take $a$ and $a+b$ in a region of the form $|\arg z|<\theta$ for some $\theta<\pi$.

Comment: But there is the constant $C$ on the RHS which we can choose to be large

Comment: @glowstonetrees: whatever the definition of $\sqrt{z}$ we use, we can choose a $b$ arbitrarily small and position $a$ so that $\sqrt{a+b}$ and $\sqrt{a}$ have opposite signs. So there can be no $C$ large enough to make the inequality true for all $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Ah you're right.  I've changed the question so that both a and b are in the upper half plane.